# Why is `$SystemCharacterEncoding` different from the actual OS character encoding on Windows?

Tags: windows, character-encoding, unicode

I was testing on Windows the command `$ wolframscript -code 'Alphabet["Greek"]' -charset UTF8` from the document of  [`wolframscript`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html#query:%7E:text=%24%20wolframscript%20%2Dcode%20%27Alphabet%5B%22Greek%22%5D%27%20%2Dcharset%20UTF8), however the output is different from the documented one.

> Documented:
>
> ```
> $ wolframscript -code 'Alphabet["Greek"]' -charset UTF8
> ```
>
> ```
> {α, β, γ, δ, ε, ζ, η, θ, ι, κ, λ, μ, ν, ξ, ο, π, ρ, σ, τ, υ, φ, χ, ψ, ω}
> ```

> Mine on Windows, either in CMD, Windows PowerShell or PS Core:
>
> ```
> C:\> wolframscript -code 'Alphabet["Greek"]' -charset UTF8
> ```
>
> ```
> Alphabet::noalpha: The alphabet Greek is not known or not available.
> Alphabet[Greek]
> ```

I also tested in WSL, and the command worked just fine as documented. I further tested the command in the interactive Wolfram environment, and found the following results.

```
In[1]:= Alphabet["Greek"]
```

```
(*Mathematica notebook with a standard MMA 12.2 front end, or wolfram CLI on Linux*)
Out[1]={α, β, γ, δ, ε, ζ, η, θ, ι, κ, λ, μ, ν, ξ, ο, π, ρ, σ, τ, υ, φ, χ, ψ, ω}

(*wolfram CLI on Windows*)
Out[1]= {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Delta], \[CurlyEpsilon], \[Zeta], \[Eta], \[Theta], \[Iota], \[Kappa],

>   \[Lambda], \[Mu], \[Nu], \[Xi], \[Omicron], \[Pi], \[Rho], \[Sigma], \[Tau], \[Upsilon], \[CurlyPhi], \[Chi],

>   \[Psi], \[Omega]}
```

Its clear that this must be some sort of encoding problem. I then tried

```
(*any method on Windows*)
In[1]:= $CharacterEncodings
        $SystemCharacterEncoding
        $CharacterEncoding
    $CharacterEncoding = "UTF-8";
        $CharacterEncoding

Out[1]= {"AdobeStandard", "ASCII", "CP936", "CP949", "CP950", \
         "EUC-JP", "EUC", "IBM-850", "ISO8859-10", "ISO8859-11", "ISO8859-13", \
         "ISO8859-14", "ISO8859-15", "ISO8859-16", "ISO8859-1", "ISO8859-2", \
         "ISO8859-3", "ISO8859-4", "ISO8859-5", "ISO8859-6", "ISO8859-7", \
         "ISO8859-8", "ISO8859-9", "ISOLatin1", "ISOLatin2", "ISOLatin3", \
         "ISOLatin4", "ISOLatinCyrillic", "Klingon", "koi8-r", \
         "MacintoshArabic", "MacintoshChineseSimplified", \
         "MacintoshChineseTraditional", "MacintoshCroatian", \
         "MacintoshCyrillic", "MacintoshGreek", "MacintoshHebrew", \
         "MacintoshIcelandic", "MacintoshKorean", \
         "MacintoshNonCyrillicSlavic", "MacintoshRomanian", "MacintoshRoman", \
         "MacintoshRomanPDFExport", "MacintoshThai", "MacintoshTurkish", \
         "MacintoshUkrainian", "Math1", "Math2", "Math3", "Math4", "Math5", \
         "Mathematica1", "Mathematica2", "Mathematica3", "Mathematica4", \
         "Mathematica5", "Mathematica6", "Mathematica7", "PrintableASCII", \
         "ShiftJIS", "Symbol", "UTF-8", "UTF8", "WindowsANSI", \
         "WindowsBaltic", "WindowsCyrillic", "WindowsEastEurope", \
         "WindowsGreek", "WindowsThai", "WindowsTurkish", "ZapfDingbats"}

Out[2]= "CP936"

Out[3]= "UTF-8"

Out[4]= "UTF-8"
```

(Note that this change have no impact on the behavior of the MMA front end; also, putting `$CharacterEncoding="UTF-8"` in the kernel `init.m` fails.)

It is clear that `-charset UTF8` successfully set `$CharacterEncoding` to `UTF-8`, and this tripped `wolframscript` from providing the output.

```
C:\> wolframscript -code '$SystemCharacterEncoding' -charset UTF8
CP936
C:\> wolframscript -code '$CharacterEncoding' -charset UTF8
UTF8
```

But again, why is the kernel using `CP936` (it's the `GBK` chinese encoding)?

Testing in the shells I got

```
REM in CMD
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 65001
```

```
# in PowerShell
C:\> [System.Text.Encoding]::Default

Preamble          :
BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 65001
```

It's clear that my OS is using UTF-8 universally.

Thus, I wonder:

- How is `$SystemCharacterEncoding` determined?